# Given a value on the first of a month, add values to it for other days of the month

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe `df1` that looks like this. The date format is M/D/Y.

| date | a |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 100 |
| 2/1/2001 | 101 |

And another dataframe `df2` that represents outflows and looks like this:

| date | a |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 2 |
| 1/2/2001 | 3 |
| 1/3/2001 | -2 |
| 1/4/2001 | 0 |

Desired output df:

| date | a |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 100 |
| 1/2/2001 | 98 |
| 1/3/2001 | 101 |
| 1/4/2001 | 99 |

I need to take the `df1` values from the first of every month as the starting value. For each subsequent day of the month, I want to add the values from `df2` from the starting value of `df1` and place the results in `df3`.

Comment: please explain what calculations or whatever needs to be done to get to the desired output ? What have you tried so far? any code ?

Comment: also, what is the format of your dates? M/D/Y or D/M/Y?

Comment: the format of the post is M/D/Y. I'll update the post to reflect that.

Comment: This is yet another case where it would be smarter to process your data BEFORE you take it into pandas.  To do this, you'll have to iterate over the rows, and that's slow in pandas.  Did this come from CSV files?

Comment: the calculations are unclear, can you explicit?

Comment: @TimRoberts how would you recommend preprocessing this data?

Comment: Where did it come from?  If you have two CSV files, for example, you can read the two of them in parallel and create new detail lines in a list.  ARE they coming from CSV files?

Comment: How do you compute `100`? Shouldn't it be `100+2`?

Comment: @mozway I believe you start with the 100 and subtract the 2 to get the next day's starting amount.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, they're coming from CSV files.

Comment: @Tim so it's not well described or there is a mistake

Comment: @mozway tim is correct, sorry for being unclear. `df2` represents the amount that should be added or substracted from 1/1/2001 to get 1/2/2001's starting value

Comment: Yes, but it's not consistent.  Day 1 is subtracted (100 - 2 => 98), but day 2 is added (98 + 3 => 101).

Comment: @throwaway2100000 how do you define whether a values is added or subtracted?

Comment: @mozway yeah my mistake. they should always be added

Comment: I provided a (vectorial) answer for the "always added" scenario, you can tweak it to your needs (e.g., performing a subtraction, adding a `shift`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, this does what you ask.  Your own data is inconsistent, however.  Your text says you ADD the number to the inventory; on the first day, you SUBTRACT the number, but you add the rest.

So, given "x1.csv":

```
date,inventory
1/1/2001,100
2/1/2001,101
3/1/2001,103
```

and "x2.csv":

```
date,update
1/1/2001,2
1/2/2001,3
1/3/2001,-2
1/4/2001,0
2/1/2001,5
2/2/2001,3
2/3/2001,-10
3/1/2001,0
3/2/2001,0
```

This Python code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

f1 = csv.reader( open('x1.csv'))
f2 = csv.reader( open('x2.csv'))

# Read the first file into a dictionary.

inventory = {}
for row in f1:
    if row[0] != 'date':
        inventory[row[0]] = int(row[1])

# Now process each line in the detail list.

current = 0
rows = []
for row in f2:
    if row[0] == 'date':
        continue
    if row[0] in inventory:
        current = inventory[row[0]]
    rows.append( (row[0],str(current)) )
    current += int(row[1])

df = pd.DataFrame( rows, columns=['date','level'])
print(df)
```

produces this output:

```
       date level
0  1/1/2001   100
1  1/2/2001   102
2  1/3/2001   105
3  1/4/2001   103
4  2/1/2001   101
5  2/2/2001   106
6  2/3/2001   109
7  3/1/2001   103
8  3/2/2001   103
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic is still unclear, but for the global logic of merging, you can use `merge` on the month period:

```
df2['a'] += df2.merge(df1,
          left_on=pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], dayfirst=False).dt.to_period('M'),
          right_on=pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], dayfirst=False).dt.to_period('M'),
          how='left', suffixes=('_', '')
          )['a']
```

output:

```
       date    a
0  1/1/2001  102
1  1/2/2001  103
2  1/3/2001   98
3  1/4/2001  100
```

output of the intermediate:

```
df2.merge(df1,
          left_on=pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], dayfirst=False).dt.to_period('M'),
          right_on=pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], dayfirst=False).dt.to_period('M'),
          how='left', suffixes=('_', '')
          )['a']

0    100
1    100
2    100
3    100
Name: a, dtype: int64
```